Breakdown with respect to a non stratification variable
Suppose we want to study the Investment of enterprises in a country. Suppose the enterprises are stratified by number of employees: three strata $s_1$ from $1$ to $9$ employees, $s_2$ from $10$ to $49$ employees and $S_3$ $\ge 50$ employees. We take a stratified simple random sampling. The formula for the total investment
is given by $$ I= N_1\overline i_1+N_2\overline i_2+ N_3\overline i_3$$
where $N_j$ is the population number of enterprises in the stratum $s_j$
and $\overline i_j$ is the mean investment of the sampled $n_j$ enterprises from stratum $s_j$.
Now suppose for simplicity that the enterprises in the population have only two industrial activities, $A_1$ and $A_2$. I want to break down the total investment found above by sector of activity, which means $I=I_1+I_2$ where $I_1$ is the total investmenet in activity $A_1$ and similarly for $I_2$. How can this be done knowing that I did not take the sector of activity as a variable of stratification from the start? Is it mandatory that any breakdown of the total investment with respect to any variable $x$ should be done by taking the breakdown variable $x$ as a stratification variable before selecting the sample?

It's fine to break the results down by non-stratification variables. The computation is a little more complicated -- you can't just analyse $A_1$ and $A_2$ separately because the sampling isn't independent. However, any survey analysis software can handle this.

Could you please give me the formulas for $I_1$ or $I_2$ or any reference dealing with this situation, I could not find any reference for this, thank you very much!

@Ben https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577164/estimating-a-population-total-from-a-stratified-simple-random-sample
